# Is polarization of light preserved in gravitational lensing?

Tags: polarization, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, gravitational-lensing

Space should not have torque since the stress energy tensor is symmetrical. That would imply that gravity can not turn a polarization plane of an electromagnetic wave. Have any changes of electromagnetic polarization (Faraday rotation) been observed in different paths in gravitational lensing?

Comment: See [Gravitational Lensing of Gravitational Waves: Rotation of Polarization Plane](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07486) for a theoretical discussion.